# Storing user-specific API keys in DB

Tags: security, meteor, password-protection, password-encryption, meteor-accounts

So I am programming a timetable app in meteor, using the [UNTIS](http://www.grupet.at/) backend. The problem I'm facing right now is, that I don't want each user to re-enter their passwords each time there is a request to the server. Sometimes I can't even (for example at 6 am to check if the first lesson isn't cancelled after all).

The problem is, that the password is needed in **plain**. So the password has to be accesible in plain at some point or another on the server.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The way I solved this problem:

I created a Meteor settings file:

`/development.json`

```js
{
  "ENCRYPT_PASSW_ENCRYPTION_KEY": "*some long encryption key*",
  "ENCRYPT_PASSW_SALT_LENGTH": 32,
  "ENCRYPT_PASSW_USER_KEY_LENGTH": 32,
  "ENCRYPT_PBKDF2_ROUNDS": 100,
  "ENCRYPT_PBKDF2_DIGEST": "sha512",
  "ENCRYPT_PASSW_ALGORITHM": "aes-256-ctr"
}
```

In order to be able to use these settings in your meteor app, you will have to start meteor like this: `meteor run --settings development.json`

Sidenote: Of course you have to add your own parameters. These are just the development settings. You will have to choose your own parameters, depending on the importance of your data. (PBKDF2_ROUNDS should be chosen to fit your host system. I've read [somewhere](https://security.stackexchange.com/a/3993) that a hash should take **at least** 241 milliseconds)

Some server side functions:

```js
// server/lib/encryption.js
const crypto = require("crypto");

// generate a cryptograhpically secure salt
// with the length specified in the settings
generateUserSalt = function (length = Meteor.settings.ENCRYPT_PASSW_SALT_LENGTH) {
  return crypto.randomBytes(length).toString("base64");
}

// encrypt a password with a key, derived from the
// application key plus the users salt
encryptUserPass = function (uid, pass, salt = false) {
  const key       = getUserKey(uid, salt),
        algorithm = Meteor.settings.ENCRYPT_PASSW_ALGORITHM,
        cipher    = crypto.createCipher(algorithm, key);

  return cipher.update(pass,'utf8','hex') + cipher.final('hex');
}

// decrypt a password with the same key
decryptUserPass = function (uid, ciphertext, salt = false) {
    const key       = getUserKey(uid, salt),
          algorithm = Meteor.settings.ENCRYPT_PASSW_ALGORITHM,
          decipher  = crypto.createDecipher(algorithm, key);

    return decipher.update(ciphertext,'hex','utf8') + decipher.final('utf8');
}

// generate the user-specific key that derives from
// the applications main encryption key plus the users
// specific salt. this is only needed in this scope
function getUserKey (uid, salt = false) {
  // if no salt is given, take it from the user db
  if (salt === false) {
    const usr = Meteor.users.findOne(uid);


    if (!usr || !usr.api_private || !usr.api_private.salt) {
      throw new Meteor.Error("no-salt-given", "The salt from user with id" + uid + " couldn't be located. Maybe it's not set?");
    }

    salt = usr.untis_private.salt;
  }

  const systemKey = Meteor.settings.ENCRYPT_PASSW_ENCRYPTION_KEY,
           rounds = Meteor.settings.ENCRYPT_PBKDF2_ROUNDS,
           length = Meteor.settings.ENCRYPT_PASSW_USER_KEY_LENGTH,
           digest = Meteor.settings.ENCRYPT_PBKDF2_DIGEST;

  const userKey = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(systemKey, salt, rounds, length, digest);

  return userKey.toString('hex');
}
```

And now I can encrypt each users password with a unique key like this:

```js
// either with generating a salt (then the uid is not needed)
let salt     = generateUserSalt(),
    encPass  = encryptUserPass(0, pass, salt);
// or when the user already has a salt (salt is in db)
let encPass2 = encryptUserPass(uid, pass);
```

Decrypting is also verry easy:

```js
let pass     = decryptUserPass(0, passEnc, salt);
// or
let pass2    = decryptUserPass(uid, passEnc);
```

### Explanation

Of course I know, that this is still pretty bad in terms of security (storing things on the server that can be reversed into user's passwords). The reason why I think this is okay:

Each users password is encrypted like this:

```
AES(password, PBKDF2(global-encryption-key + salt))
```

This means that:

1. each user's password is encrypted with a different key
2. no encryption keys are saved in the db

Why I think this is a good sollution:

1. In case the database is leaked, the attacker will firstly need to guess the AES key correctly for one specific user and then reverse the PBKDF2 to find the global-encryption-key. or
2. Guess the global-encryption-key

Therefore you should chose a rather large global-encryption-key.

### Facts about salts

1. NEVER use a salt twice
2. Change salts together with passwords (don't reuse them)
3. Salts should be long: rule of thumb: make the salt as long the output of the hash function (sha256 = 32 bytes)

[more about salting things](https://crackstation.net/hashing-security.htm)